# MYSQL + PHP: Arrays and Loops

Tags: php, mysql

From a list of users, I need to issue points based on who came in first and according to how many points I have left to give.

I was thinking...

1. Get a list of new users and calculate points to be given.
2. Add those points to any points left over from yesterday.
3. Generate the list of users both old and new.
4. Loop through the users and give them 1 point each according to who came in first without exceeding daily points cap per person and total points for the day.

Now I already have 1-3 down, but I'm having trouble with 4.

What's the best way to get this done?

Sample Data:

```
UserId | Points | Date In
   1   |   3    |   2014-09-22 12:00:00
   2   |   2    |   2014-09-22 12:00:02
   3   |   1    |   2014-09-22 01:10:05
```

As you can see, UserId 1 logged in first, he gets 1 point. When UserId 2 logs in, UserId 1 gets another point and UserId 2 gets one point. When UserId 3 logs in, UserId 1 gets another point, and so does UserId 2 and 3. This goes on until a user reaches the daily cap or there are no more points to give.

I'd appreciate any help I can get...

Thanks!

Edit: Sample of where I want to be at:

Pseudocode:

```
WHILE points <= 0 {
DO {
list users and distribute points to users by cycling through each one
} WHILE dailypointscap <=10
```

** if dailypointscap of user reaches 10 points before points reaches 0, remove user from list and then cycle through list again.

I hope I am making sense here...

Comment: what if a user log in twice ?

Comment: Good question. The system only logs you in once. And multiple log-ins after your initial log-in will be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already got the list of user IDs which are eligible for points from the database, sorted by login date. Assuming each user is stored in an array like this

```
$users = [
    ['id' => 1, 'points' => 0],
    ['id' => 4, 'points' => 0],
    ['id' => 8, 'points' => 0],
    ['id' => 2, 'points' => 0],
];
```

and the remaining points in `$points`, you can iterate over the users to update the new points:

```
$total = 20;
$assigned = [];
do {
    foreach($users as $user) {
        if (!array_key_exists($user['id'], $assigned)) {
            $assigned[$user['id']] = 0;
        }
        foreach($assigned as $id => $points) {
            if($points < 10) {
                $assigned[$id]++;
                $total--;
            }
            if ($total == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
} while ($points > 0);
```

This works because PHP keeps track of the order of entries in an array independently of the keys.

You can then update the users in the database.

Comment: Each time a user is given a point, a record of that transaction must be saved. Which is why I was looking at a loop to get this done...

Comment: Do you need to generate a table record or write a logfile?

Comment: There's a record that gets generated every time a point is issued to a user.

Comment: Updated answer. You need to adjust the TRIGGER to your table names.

Comment: Hi Andy! Thanks but I already have a query to save the points and log who the points went to so I can't use triggers. If you can help me with the loop issue, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I will try this. However, looking at the code, it looks like it will simply iterate through each user and give them 1 point until 10 or points = 0. Basically, it's correct, but if you go back to my Sample Data, you'll see that the issue I'm having is that when I get the list of users, each user added to the list restarts the loop. Which is why UserId 1 has 2 more points than UserId 2 and UserId 2 has 1 more point than UserId 3...

Comment: So you want to calculate the entire ranking after everybody has logged in instead of running this code every time someone logs in?

Comment: Thanks! We're getting there. I posted the original function that distributes the points in order to get a better idea of how to implement your solution...

Comment: @JonDavis I'm considering myself a patient person, but this is just beyond the scope of this platform. Please Accept this answer and work out the rest yourself or ask a new question for a new problem.